# WSGI application middleware to handle SQLAlchemy session

Tags: sqlalchemy, wsgi, middleware

My WSGI application uses SQLAlchemy. I want to start session when request starts, commit it if it's dirty and request processing finished successfully, make rollback otherwise. So, I need to implement behavior of Django's `TransactionMiddleware`.

So, I suppose that I should create WSGI middleware and make following stuff:

1. Create and add DB session to `environ` on pre-processing.
2. Get DB session from `environ` and call `commit()` on post-processing, if no errors occurred.
3. Get DB session from `environ` and call `rollback()` on post-processing, if some errors occurred.

Step 1 is obvious for me:

```
class DbSessionMiddleware:
def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    environ['db_session'] = create_session()
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

Step 2 and 3 - not. I found the [example](http://docs.repoze.org/moonshining/pep333.html#example-middleware) of post-processing task:

```
class Caseless:
def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    for chunk in self.app(environ, start_response):
        yield chunk.lower()
```

It contains comment:

> Note that the `__call__` function is a Python generator, which is typical for this sort of “post-processing” task.

Could you please clarify how does it work and how can I solve my issue similarly.

Thanks,
  Boris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For step 1 I use SQLAlchemy [scoped sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions):

```
engine = create_engine(settings.DB_URL, echo=settings.DEBUG, client_encoding='utf8')
Base = declarative_base()

sm = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
get_session = scoped_session(sm)
```

They return the same thread-local session for each get_session() call.

Step 2 and 3 for now is following:

```
class DbSessionMiddleware:
def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    try:
        db.get_session().begin_nested()
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
    except BaseException:
        db.get_session().rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        db.get_session().commit()
```

As you can see, I start nested transaction on session to be able to rollback even queries that were already committed in views.

Comment: Can I safely use `db.get_session()` inside `self.app`? For example, like this - `db.get_session().query(...)`? Or do I get problems with thread local storage?